# Same number of solutions to $ax^m+by^n\equiv c\pmod{p}$ and $ax^{m'}+by^{n'}\equiv c\pmod{p}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble with the last problem of Chapter 4 in Ireland and Rosen's Number Theory.

> Show that $ax^m+by^n\equiv c\pmod{p}$ has the same number of solutions as $ax^{m'}+by^{n'}\equiv c\pmod{p}$ where $m'=(m,p-1)$ and $n'=(n,p-1)$.

I let $g$ be a primitive root, and $m=m'i'$ and $n=n'j'$ for some $i'$ and $j'$. Then if $(g^i,g^j)$ is a solution to the first equation, $(g^{ii'},g^{jj'})$ is a solution to the second.

I also tried working out an example. I considered the equations
$$
2x^3+3y^2\equiv 1\pmod{5},\qquad 2x+3y^2\equiv 1\pmod{5}.
$$
The first has five solutions $(2,0),(3,2),(3,3),(4,1),(4,4)$ and the second has five solutions $(2,2),(2,3),(3,0),(4,1),(4,4)$. The only relation I could see between the solutions is that $0,1,4$ are fixed, and it seems $2$ and $3$ swap places.

However, I don't know how to apply this to a general proof of the statement. How could one do that? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have the same equation twice, and the strange relations for $m$ and $n$ just mean that $n$ and $m$ divide $p - 1$. Please correct the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the fact that the non-zero residue classes modulo $p$ form a cyclic group of order $p-1$. Combine that with the (hopefully known to you) bit that in a cyclic group $C_k$ of order $k$ an element is an $r^{th}$ power if and only if it is a $d^{th}$ power, where $d=\gcd(r,k)$. Moreover, the number of times you get the same element as a power will be the same in both cases. [Edit] This is because the solutions of the equation $x^d=1$ form the kernel $K$ of the homomorphism $g\mapsto g^t$ from $C_k$ to itself with both $t=r$ and $t=d$. The solutions of $x^t=y$ (for some $y\in C_k$) then are either the empty set or a coset of $K$. In the latter case the number of solutions is $|K|$. [/Edit]

---

In your example case of $2x^3$ modulo $5$ we have $p-1=4$. As $\gcd(3,4)=1$, an element is a third power if and only if it is a first power. The latter is obviously always true, so in this cubing should be a bijection of the residue classes. Indeed,
$$
1^3\equiv1, 2^3=8\equiv3, 3^3=27\equiv 2, 4^3=64\equiv 4,
$$
all the congruences where $\pmod 5$.

Modulo $7$ it will be more interesting. Let's try fourth powers this time. Now $p-1=6$ and
$\gcd(4,p-1)=2$, so the theory tells us that any (non-zero) residue class occurs as a square as often as as a fourth power. This time, all congruences $\pmod 7$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
1\equiv1^2\equiv6^2\equiv 1^4\equiv6^4,\\
2\equiv3^2\equiv4^2\equiv 2^4\equiv5^4,\\
4\equiv2^2\equiv5^2\equiv 3^4\equiv4^4.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks Jyrki, I understand an element is an $r$th power iff it is a $d$th power, but how do you know that an element is an $r$th power the same number of times that it is a $d$th power? After that, I think I understand the solution in full.

Comment: @Dedede: I added an explanation in terms of cosets of a subgroup.

Comment: How do you find that the kernel of $g\mapsto g^r$ is contained in the solutions to $x^d=1$? And then if $x_0$ is a solution to $x^t=y$ for some $y$, then every element of the coset $x_0K$ is a solution too. But all I see from this is that the number of ways an element $y$ can be written as a power of $d$ or a power of $r$ is going to be a multiple of $|K|$, but not necessarily the same multiple.

Comment: @Dedede: The kernels of both these maps are the unique subgroup of order $d$ of $C_k$. This is usually explained in lecture notes at the time cyclic groups are studied. To answer the second question: If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are roots of $x^t=y$, then $x_1x_2^{-1}$ is in the kernel of $x\mapsto x^t$. Conversely, if $x_1$ is a root of $x^t=y$, and $z\in K$, then $x_2=x_1z$ is also a root.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with your initial attempt.  Find an inverse to your map $(g^i, g^j) \mapsto (g^{ii'}, g^{jj'})$.

Comment: I was thinking if $(g^k,g^\ell)$ is a solution to the second equation, then $(g^{k/i'},g^{\ell/j'})$ is a solution to the first, but I don't know if I can necessarily divide.

Comment: That's too simple to be correct.  Somewhere you have to use the facts $m' = (m, p-1)$ and $n' = (n, p-1)$.  So far, you have only used $m'|m$ and $n'|n$, which are much weaker facts.

Comment: Oh right, writing $m'=sm+t(p-1)$ and $n'=un+v(p-1)$, it follows that $(g^{ks},g^{\ell u})$ is a solution to the first equation. But how can we be sure the number of solutions is still the same if there may be repeats?

Comment: Show that the 2 maps you have constructed are inverses of each other.  Then the number of solutions must be the same.

Comment: Composing the maps, I get $(g^i,g^j)\mapsto (g^{ii'},g^{jj'})\mapsto (g^{ii's},g^{jj'u})$. So I need $ii's\equiv i$ and $jj'u\equiv j\pmod{p-1}$ for the composition to be the identity. I can't figure out why the congruences are true though.

Comment: Remember that $i' = m/m'$, and also you have $m' \equiv sm$ (mod $p-1$) from your definition of $s$.

Comment: So it seems $$ii's=ism/m'\equiv ism/sm\equiv i\pmod{p-1},$$ but how does one justify dividing by $sm$?

Comment: Sorry, this is messier than I thought it would be, because as I just noticed, you still haven't used the full force of $m' = (m,p-1)$ (to write the equation involving $s$ and $t$, you've only used $(m,p-1)|m'$).  Here is a better argument: We just need to show that the map $x \mapsto x^{i'}$ is invertible in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, and to do that, it's enough to show that $i' = m/m'$ is relatively prime to $p-1$.  That's true because if they had a common divisor $d>1$, then $m'd$ would be an even larger common factor of $m$ and $p-1$.

Comment: I'm not sure that follows. For example, if $m=4$ and $p=7$, then $m'=(4,6)=2$, so $i'=2$, but $(i',p-1)=(2,6)=2\neq 1$.

Comment: Argh, I keep getting this wrong.  Basically, the problem comes down to showing that $m'$ is a multiple of $m$ modulo $p-1$: We need to solve $m' \equiv xm$ (mod $p-1$) for $x$. Dividing everything by $m'$ (including the modulus!), we need to solve $1 \equiv x(m/m')$ (mod $(p-1)/m'$) where both of the fractions are really integers.  Now it *is* true that $m/m'$ is relatively prime to $(p-1)/m'$, because if they had a common divisor $d>1$, then $m'd$ would be an even larger common factor of $m$ and $p-1$.

Comment: As I wrote above, since $m' \equiv sm\ (p-1)$, as is shown by the above comment using Bézout's identity, we get $x^{m'} \equiv x^{sm}\ (p)$, by Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Yes, but isn't it already clear from $m'=(m,p-1)$ that $m'$ is a multiple of $m$ modulo $p-1$ by applying Bezout's identity. So $i'$ is coprime to $(p-1)/m'$, but how does that help in showing $x\mapsto x^{i'}$ is invertble in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$?